# ActiveAdmin :select drop-down defaults to current value in development but defaults to blank in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-6

I have the following ActiveAdmin form:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Timesheet Details" do
    f.input :jobs_assigned_worker, :label => "Worker", as: :select, collection: Worker.all
    f.input :worked_time_hours,    :label => "Worked Time (Hours)"
    f.input :worked_time_mins,     :label => "Worked Time (Minutes)"
    f.input :driving_time_hours,   :label => "Driving Time (Hours)"
    f.input :driving_time_mins,    :label => "Driving Time (Minutes)"
    f.input :spent_dollars,        :label => "Extra Money Spent"
  end
  f.actions
end
```

When I use this form in the edit view, the select drop-down automatically defaults to the present value. However in production the drop-down is for some reason defaulting to the blank value at the top (why is that blank value there anyway?).

**EDIT**

The problem seems to be that ActiveAdmin doesn't understand the association and is unable to select associated object by default. I need to figure out how to code the `f.input` for the association. The form is for a Timesheet. A Timesheet `has_many` JobsAssignedWorkers and each JobsAssignedWorker has a Worker.

Comment: In development, what happens when there isn't a present value? Is it possible that in production you have a Worker with no label?

Comment: Every Timesheet has to have a Worker associated with it

Comment: The problem seems to be that ActiveAdmin doesn't understand the association and is unable to select associated object by default. I need to figure out how to code the `f.input` for the association

Answer (score 24):

If you want to include blank value:

```
f.input :jobs_assigned_worker,
  label: 'Worker',
  as: :select,
  collection: -> { Worker.pluck(:name) },
  include_blank: true
```

If you don't want to include blank value:

```
f.input :jobs_assigned_worker,
  label: 'Worker',
  as: :select,
  collection: -> { Worker.pluck(:name) },
  include_blank: false
```

If you want to have blank value, but don't want to allow it as an option:

```
f.input :jobs_assigned_worker,
  label: 'Worker',
  as: :select,
  collection: -> { Worker.pluck(:name) },
  include_blank: true,
  allow_blank: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set 'include_blank' option.

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs "Timesheet Details" do
        f.input :jobs_assigned_worker, :label => "Worker", as: :select, collection: Worker.all, include_blank: false
        f.input :worked_time_hours,    :label => "Worked Time (Hours)"
        f.input :worked_time_mins,     :label => "Worked Time (Minutes)"
        f.input :driving_time_hours,   :label => "Driving Time (Hours)"
        f.input :driving_time_mins,    :label => "Driving Time (Minutes)"
        f.input :spent_dollars,        :label => "Extra Money Spent"
    end
    f.actions
end
```

Answer (score 1):

to avoid persist the blank value just add in your select this option:

```
include_hidden: false
```